# Timing Clock Animation

Tags: ios, animation, ios7

How would I add an animation where a white 'clock hand' go's around like a rotating clock which would go from blank to after 2 min, filled by rotating in the middle??

Thanks,
Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use a great library called `THCircularProgressView` see: https://github.com/tiagomnh/THCircularProgressView . This library takes care of all the animations and its just an `UIView` subclass, so you can make it any size you want and customize it however you want.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct as that will help future readers.